# Make embedded Tomcat log to certain file with log4j in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, logging

**Introduction**

I've been looking for this fix for some time now but no luck so far. I'm building a Java webapp which uses embedded Tomcat as servlet. I have set log4j as my main logger and the logs post to the file specified successfully. Because the Tomcat is embedded I cannot find this catalina.out file that I've seen in so many answers through SO and other forums.

**Problem**

What I want is to make Tomcat log with log4j to the same file I use for logging for the whole webapp. How can I do this? Is there a way to do this programmatically?

*P.S.* :
I'm using Windows as an OS and the Tomcat version is 8.0.30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was way simpler than I thought, so I'm just leaving the answer here for anyone who might have the same problem.

I made a function `initializeLogging()`

```
private static void initializeLogging()


{  
  //Getting the current timestamp to use in log file naming
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  java.text.DateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddHHmmss");
  String timestamp = df.format(calendar.getTime());

  ConfigurationBuilder< BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();

  builder.setStatusLevel(Level.ALL);
  builder.setConfigurationName("RollingBuilder");
  // create a console appender      
  AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE").addAttribute("target",
                                                                                                   ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
  appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
          .addAttribute("pattern", "<%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}>  %p (%t).  %m%n"));
  builder.add(appenderBuilder);
  // create a rolling file appender
  LayoutComponentBuilder layoutBuilder = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
          .addAttribute("pattern", "<%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}>  %p (%t).  %m%n");
  ComponentBuilder triggeringPolicy = builder.newComponent("Policies")              
          .addComponent(builder.newComponent("SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy").addAttribute("size", "100M"));
  //specifying log file name as well ss log file name if the first exceeds maximum size => 100M
  appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("rolling", "RollingFile")
          .addAttribute("fileName", "logs/myLogging" + "_" + timestamp + ".log")              
          .addAttribute("FilePattern","logs/myLogging"+"_"+ timestamp + "%d{yyyyMMddHHmmss}" + ".log")
          .add(layoutBuilder)
          .addComponent(triggeringPolicy);
  builder.add(appenderBuilder);

  // create the new logger
  builder.add(builder.newLogger("myLogger", Level.ALL)
          .add(builder.newAppenderRef("rolling"))
          .addAttribute("additivity", false));

  builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(Level.ALL)
          .add(builder.newAppenderRef("rolling")));
  LoggerContext ctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());      


 }
```

so what this function does is to give a pattern at each entry to the logs and direct the logs to a file specified by me. Now every time I want to log something I just have to call `Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger('myLogger)`

So there it is a quick programmatic only log4j initialization.

Answer (score 0):

By default tomcat uses `[CATALINA_HOME]/conf/logging.properties`. In there edit the below properties:

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = **YOUR_PATH_HERE**
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.
```

Comment: As [CATALINA_HOME] I get the tomcat directory in my webapp project which does not have a conf directory inside. It only has a work directory. I tried looking for the logging.properties file but couldn't find it. Also this does not log with log4j. Is it possible to do this programmatically?